# I'm having problems with my for-loop and getting following message: KeyError: 2

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I'm getting following error: Stats  PlayerList=competitionList[j] KeyError: 2
I have saved many lists in competitionList, which is a dictionary. And I want to iterate through all the objects in the lists in my dictionary.

```
def Stats(competitionList, playerList):
        no_of_competitions = int(len(competitionList))
        x = (len(playerList))
        for i in range(no_of_competitions):
            for j in range (int(x)):
            #My error occurs here
                PlayerList=competitionList[j]
                for player in PlayerList: 
                    print("player: ", player.name)
                    print ("list :", player.name, player.victories)
```

Comment: why do you cast to int no_of_competitions? It's already an integer.

Comment: To state the error in other words: You have no key in your dictionary which is the integer 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is simply stating that in this line:

```
PlayerList=competitionList[j]
```

The dictionary `competitionList` doesn't contain one of the keys in `range(x)`, in this case, the key `2`. Make sure that either:

1. All the values in the range are present in `competitionList`
2. Or that you only iterate over the values that are actually present in the dictionary

For the second option, this should simplify things and make them work:

```
for players in competitionList.values():
    for player in players:
        print("player: ", player.name)
        print ("list : ", player.name, player.victories)
```

Comment: thanks the code is working now. One small question how come it works when you add values ?

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values), `values()` retrieves the dictionary's _values_, which is the ones we're interested in. We can ignore the _keys_ for this problem in particular.

Answer (score 0):

You use `j` to access `competitionList`. But `j` referes to `x` and `x` is the length of `playerList`. `playerList` and `competitionList` can defer in length so thats why you get this type of error.